# Count total days filter mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to build a query that returns the number of days from a query in mongo. The query would be in just one column called "Date created".

In the filter I need to get the number of days from my query, for example:

Collection:

```
{
    "created_at":"2022-01-02T00:00:00",
    "type":"car"
},
{
    "created_at":"2022-01-05T00:00:00",
    "type":"car"
},
{
    "created_at":"2022-01-10T00:00:00",
    "type":"car"
}
```

Query:

```
db.pipe.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "created_at": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2022-01-01"),
                "$lte": ISODate("2022-01-22")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "total_days_date_filter": 20,
            "total_result_query": 2
        }
    }
])
```

result:

```
{
    "total_days_date_filter": 20,
    "total_result_query": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        type: 1,
         created_at: {
      $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$created_at"
       }
      }
     }
      },
    {
    "$match": {
     "created_at": {
       "$gte": ISODate("2022-01-01"),
       "$lte": ISODate("2022-01-22")
      }
    }
   },
    {
       $group: {
        _id: "total",
        totalq: {
         $sum: 1
         },
        maxd: {
          $max: "$created_at"
          },
         mind: {
           $min: "$created_at"
          }
        }
      },
        {
       $project: {
       _id: 0,
        total_result_query: {
                  $toInt: "$totalq"
         },
        total_days_day_filter: {
        $toInt: {
           $dateDiff: {
            startDate: "$mind",
            endDate: "$maxd",
            unit: "day"
          }
        }
      }
      }
     }
   ])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fmvUAisINjz)

[playground ( + search filter total days )](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KU5vOWCNkzJ)

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I needed